Why am I not getting desired result in Hot Chocolate GraphQL using in built filter?
I have a query response like below. Here, I want to filter out record where  "itemState" is "Exception". I am trying to use in build filter but looks like it is not working as expected. I tried several approaches but not getting desired approach.
What am I missing here?
Do I need to write custom filter?
BE Code:
public partial class Query
  {
      [UseFiltering(typeof(ExceptionDetailsByStockNumberFilterType))]
      public async Task<IQueryable<ExceptionDetailsByStockDto>> GetExceptionDetailsByStockNumberAsync(
          IReadOnlyList<string> stockNumber,
          ExceptionByStockNumberRequestDto exceptionByStockNumberRequest,
          CancellationToken cancellationToken,
          [Service(ServiceKind.Synchronized)] IExceptionService exceptionService)
          => await exceptionService.GetExceptionDetailsByStockNumbersAsync(stockNumber, exceptionByStockNumberRequest, cancellationToken);
  }

ExceptionDetailsByStockNumberFilterType
 public class ExceptionDetailsByStockNumberFilterType: FilterInputType<ExceptionDetailsByStockDto>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<ExceptionDetailsByStockDto> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Ignore(x => x.Id);
            descriptor.Ignore(x => x.CreatedBy);
            descriptor.Ignore(x => x.StockNumber);
            descriptor.Ignore(x => x.Vin);

            base.Configure(descriptor);
        }
    }

ExceptionDetailsByStockDto
[GraphQLName("ExceptionDetailsDto")]
public class ExceptionDetailsByStockDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string StockNumber { get; set; }
    public string Vin { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LineItemDto> LineItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PaymentDto> Payments { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

Actual Response:
{
  "data": {
    "exceptionDetailsByStockNumber": [
      {
        "vin": "2G1WB58K381303600",
        "lineItems": [
          {
            "itemState": "Reconciled",
            "reconciliationStatus": "Matched"
          },
          {
            "itemState": "Exception",
            "reconciliationStatus": "Duplicate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Desired Result:
{
  "data": {
    "exceptionDetailsByStockNumber": [
      {
        "vin": "2G1WB58K381303600",
        "lineItems": [
          {
            "itemState": "Exception",
            "reconciliationStatus": "Duplicate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Graph QL:
with where: { lineItems: { all: { itemState: { eq: "Exception" } } } }
query {
  exceptionDetailsByStockNumber(
    stockNumber: "2002705823"
    where: { lineItems: { all: { itemState: { eq: "Exception" } } } }
  ) {
    vin
    lineItems {
      itemState
      reconciliationStatus
    }
  }
}

Other approaches:

 where: { lineItems: { some: { itemState: { contains: "Exception" } } } }
 where: { lineItems: { none: { itemState: { eq: "Reconciled" } } } }

